# Overflow hidden without Width

Tags: html, css

I have one line that contains two separate strings, `foo` and `bar`. The entire `bar` string must be rendered and aligned to the right of `box`, while `foo` can be truncated via `overflow:hidden;` when necessary to preserve one line of text. The line of text if 200px wide.

My issue is that I am unsure how to apply `overflow:hidden;` to an element of unspecified width. For example, `bar` is a dynamic value. So for Page A `bar` is 50px while Page B `bar` will be 150px. As a result, I cannot hard code a `width` to `foo` to use `overflow:hidden;`.

In my example, the text spans over two lines which is not the behaviour I want. The text must fit inside one single line. If the text is too large, `overflow:hidden;` will be applied to `foo` until `foo` and `bar` will appear on one single line.

http://jsfiddle.net/U3Lhg/

```
.box { overflow:hidden; height:30px; width:200px; background:red; }
.foo { overflow:hidden; display:inline; background:aqua; }
.bar { float:right; background:yellow;}

<div class="box">
    <div class="foo">Cum sociis natoque</div>
    <div class="bar">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am slightly confused... So do you want bar to always have its full length or text and foo to be hidden if need be?? Also where do you want it to be hidden? Have it continue behind/under the text of bar?

Comment: @Kierchon Yes, you are correct. I want `bar` to have its full length of text at all times. `foo` is to have the `overflow:hidden;` applied to it. I would like to have `foo` to be hidden 15px from `bar`. It would be best if the hidden part of `foo` does not continue behind the text of `bar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a relatively simple way to implement this using a `position: absolute` approach rather than an `overflow: hidden` approach.

http://jsfiddle.net/U3Lhg/2/

```
.box {
    border: 5px solid red;
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}

.foo {
    background: aqua;

}
.bar {
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Would this meet your needs, or are there other reasons you're trying to use `overflow: hidden`? (If so, you're going to need JS.)

Answer (score 0):

Using `flex` and `text-overflow` properties of CSS

```css
.col {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.foo {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0 5px;
  background: aqua;
}
.bar {
  background: yellow;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="foo">
   Some long text Cum sociis natoque Cum sociis natoque Some long text Cum sociis natoque Cum sociis natoque 
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
    Lorem ipsum dolor
  </div>
</div>
```